# Gmail IMAP getting folderList making issue

Tags: imap

I am phasing issue of the retriving folderlist of the GMAIL using IMAP protocol.

Things is that whenever I am trying to retrive folderlist using LIST command and XLIST, but it will give me error means BAD command so is there any other command to retrive the Folderlist.

My command is like

```
byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((("$ XLIST \"\" \"*\" \r\n")).ToCharArray());
```

and  also pass the LIST Command but still I am not able to get folder list it say BAD Command not to parse.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042505/imap-gmail-getting-folder-list-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIST` (or `XLIST` on GMail) is the only way to get a folder list.  Your `LIST` command should look something like the following:

```
A001 LIST "" *
```

That retrieves all the user's folders.  If you just want top-level folders (which in GMail maps to your labels), you'd use

```
A002 LIST "" %
```

Comment: Hi dkarp I am using above commnad but I am not able to get folder list. see my modify above code.

Comment: @Jitendra: Your command looks correct.  You're sending it *after* authenticating, right?

Comment: @Jitendra: Your problem is an extra space after the `"*"` and before the `\r\n`.  Get rid of that space and it will work.

Comment: Yes dkarp I am sending this command after authenticate but I am not able to fetch it.

Comment: @Jitendra: It's the extra trailing space that's the issue.