# IMAP GMAIL getting folder list problem

Tags: c#, gmail, imap

I am working on IMAP and trying to get the list of folders in my Gmail account.

I am able to get it working with Yahoo Mail, but not Gmail.

Here's my code:

```
byte[] commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((("$ XLIST \"\" \"*\" \r\n")).ToCharArray());
```

I had tried `LIST` as well, but it's also not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This belongs to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a space between the `"*"` and the trailing `\r\n`.

Comment: @ Dear dkarp thanks a lot for your right direction.. it's woring fine. once again thanks..

Comment: Hello dkarp, is there any specific command for retriving only header nothing else. in IMAP.

Comment: @Jitendra: Yes. [`$ UID FETCH <uid> RFC822.HEADER`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.5) or `$ UID FETCH <uid> BODY.PEEK[HEADER]` will do that.  (This should really be a separate question...)